# yii2 Expandable listview?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i have just displayed a listview in yii2. it displays well but i don't want it to display all at once .like it show display the first 5 .And when i click the show more button it should display add 5 extra. and so on. till the content finishes. All i want is for the content to expand by 5 on click of a button. without refreshing the whole page.

```
     <?php
             $querycomment = comment::find()->where(['topic_id'=> Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id')])->limit(5)->all();
                $dataArr = array();
              foreach ($querycomment as $detail) {
                $dataArr[] = array(
                    'user_comment' => $detail->user_comment,
                    'created' => $detail->created,
                    'byy' => $detail->byy,
                    'name' => $detail->name,
                    'comment_id' => $detail->comment_id,
                );
              }
              $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                    'allModels' => $dataArr,
                    'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 10,
                    ],
                    'sort' => [
                        'attributes' => ['views'=>SORT_ASC]
                    ],
                ]);
    ?>  
    <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'yes']) ?>

             <?=  ListView::widget([
                 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                 'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'comment-item'],
                 'itemView' => 'commentadapter',

            ]);
                ?>
                <?php Pjax::end() ?>
  <?= Html::Button('show more', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
 'name' => 'show-more' ,'id'=>'show-more']) ?>
```

this is my controller;

```
  public function actionBlog()
    {
        return $this->render('blog',[
            'comment' => $comment,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can I know what you currently get? I guess you can do that with manual JavaScript or Dynamic Form.

Comment: you mean like append right. i just want to know if it is possible with js